# I have to implement this function in my project while I add this function I get error near new bitmap

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Public Shared Function ScaleImage(image As System.Drawing.Image, maxHeight As Integer) As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim ratio = CDbl(maxHeight) / image.Height
    Dim newWidth = CInt(Math.Truncate(image.Width * ratio))
    Dim newHeight = CInt(Math.Truncate(image.Height * ratio))
    Dim newImage = **New Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight)**
    Using g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
        g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
    End Using
    Return newImage
End Function
```

Comment: This isn't a question. Please read [ask] and do your research first on the actual error. If you then can't figure it out, include the actual error and your attempts to resolve it in your question.

Comment: I receive the  following errorOverload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:

Comment: Again, read [ask] and follow it closely. Then [edit] your question.

Comment: Anyway you're declaring your variables wrong, they're all objects. Bitmap has no `Bitmap(object, object)` constructor.

Comment: CodeCaster  When I run  this code independently it works for me while intergrating  to website it  shows  error :(( .Could you  please tell me how to make it work  for me  in website.

Comment: Replace all your equal signs with `As <type>` - where `<type>` is the wanted type of the variable. For example your first one should be `Dim ratio As Double`

Comment: I am  getting same  error. @vincet

Comment: worst title of the day

Comment: @user3697824 You deserve  a medal for being Programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently declaring everything as `Object`, the compiler does not know which type of variable you want.

You should always ensure to include that in the declaration in order to reduce the chance of complications such as this. This is what the `As` keyword is used for.

```
Dim ratio As Double = CDbl(maxHeight) / image.Height
Dim newWidth As Integer = CInt(Math.Truncate(image.Width * ratio))
Dim newHeight As Integer = CInt(Math.Truncate(image.Height * ratio))
Dim newImage As New Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight)
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
    g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
End Using
Return newImage
```

Comment: @vincet  could  you  please provide the same functionality  with  javascript

Comment: @PrashantVerma : Unfortunately no. Because A) I don't know how B) Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You'd have to ask a new question for that **but** it might not be taken well. We want to see research and effort.

Comment: Be sure to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 'til the next time you're going to ask a new question.

Comment: @vincet  I appreciate that I am  completely  new to  stack overflow

Comment: If `Object Infer On` is set, then the compiler would be able to infer the types based on the right side of the expression in most cases.  But where there might be any doubt as to the type, then I agree with specifying the type explicitly.